# Pytest - Breakpoints in tests are being skipped when debugging with VSCode

Tags: python, docker-compose, pytest, vscode-debugger

In the python module `integration_tests` I have a script to run my tests via pytest in the file `run_tests.py`:

```
import pytest

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    pytest.main(['./integration_tests/']) # breakpoint here works, but no breakpoints in test methods
```

In my `docker-compose.yml` file I attach a debugger and run the tests by setting the entrypoint:

```
entrypoint: ["/usr/src/app/cvenv/bin/python3.8", "-m", "ptvsd", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5678", "--wait", "./integration_tests/run_tests.py"]
```

The breakpoint in the `run_tests.py` file works. But no breakpoints after that are being executed.

How can I really debug the tests and not just until the pytest call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that I can use the `-m` module switch twice. So now I added the `-m pytest` switch to the entrypoint command with the ptvsd debugging option.
Now this command runs the visual studio debugger and calls the tests.

I couldn't debug the tests using the `pytest.main` call because it creates a seperate thread.